# Looking for C++ library to extract image in PDF together with location

Tags: c++, pdf

I am developing applications using C++ at university.

As a requirement of the application, it is necessary to extract data from a PDF file together with location (x position and y position on a page) in which texts and images are embedded.

Is there a useful C++ library?
Or should I analyze the data structure of the PDF file and extract the data?

notes:
 I did not know that such a question is inappropriate on this site.
 Because the kind one answered, I will leave it untouched.
 I will be careful about the question content in the future

Comment: One of the standard close reasons for off-topicness is "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  This fits the bill.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start might be Imagemagik https://imagemagick.org/script/api.php